# Cypress: scrolling elements into view - true or false

Tags: javascript, testing, dom, cypress

Cypress docs says:

> Before interacting with an element, we will always scroll it into view (including any of its parent containers). Even if the element was visible without scrolling, we perform the scrolling algorithm...

But I faced a problem that shows that they do not: I am trying to click an element which is out of visible part of the screen. And the log says that the element is not visible. I do exactly the same thing but use `scrollTo()` command at first. The click is performed without any problem.

So is the qutation true or false?

And how the problem could be solved?

(`click({force:true})` does not work as well).

Comment: Did you checked `scrollIntoView() ` method? Also can you please check what viewport configuration you have?

Comment: Thank you @Darpan Rangari. It works with scrollIntoView(). The only thing I have added to make it really working is 500ms of waiting after scrolling. So the answer to the question is false?